# Capturing speech audio and video with a smartphone?

Tags: video, audio, software-recommendation, hardware, recommendation

I'm interested in using a smartphone as an expensive tool to capture speech audio and video. Perhaps equipped with a tripod, add-on wide-angle lens and wireless microphone for the speaker.

Anyone with experience in doing something like this willing to share your experiences?

Are the add-on wide-angle lenses any good for this? I have a Galaxy S8. What about video capture software? Is the built-in camera app ok for this purpose or should I use a 3rd party app?

Any experiences with non-bluetooth wireless mics? I'm worried about BT range and other connectivity issues.

Comment: Here's a pro talking about filming a short on an iPhone and it will give you some insights on the cons, it's do-able but there are some gotchas.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJhsg9KhGKQ

Answer (score 1):

Were I work we used an iPhone 7 and a Samsung S8+ for an experimental web series  to capture video. The result was awesome, specially when you use stuff like the [DJI Osmo Mobile 2 Smartphone Gimbal](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1383438-REG/dji_cp_zm_00000064_01_osmo_mobile_2.html). (The series is not yet released, will updated when the editing is finished)

At first we used Bluetooth microphones but there is a lot of issues with the range and sound quality. We used the [Sennheiser ew 112-p](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/618739-REG/Sennheiser_EW_112P_G3_A_EW112_p_G3_Camera_Mount.html?sts=pi) and recorded the audio on a [Tascam DR-05](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/757065-REG/Tascam_DR_05_DR_05_Portable_Handheld_Digital.html?sts=pi) . This is a little expensive, an alternative will be to use another cellphone and record the audio there with a wired microphone.

No need for a third party app, specially on the Samsung S8, where you can manually edit all the settings. You should consider the Samsung S8 has a 10 minute time limit when recording 4K video.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
What kind of content are you recording?

Just wondering should I use a wide-angle lens for recording the talk, so that we can have a focused image while still be able to capture a relatively wide stage are to allow the speaker to move around.

Any experiences in recording talks?
Does a wide-angle lens help?

Comment: It was a suspense web series. 
I don't really like lenses on cellphones, I prefer to move around the cellphone until I have the correct angle or set the cellphone on a tripod and move it with the presenter. You have a great image sensor on your cellphone, don't damage the image by putting a lens over it.

Answer (score 0):

For audio, I would suggest using a Rode SmartLav+ - it's only £42 but the audio it provides is nice and crisp, but even more so with the mini 'deadcat' you can get as an accessory. For tripods/stabilisers, I would suggest a Steadicam Solo (this has a built-in monopod, and is a bit overkill, but would work fine) and for a tighter budget maybe this (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Handheld-Stabilizer-Adjustable-Steadicam-Monopod/dp/B06Y67P6LC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1520779509&sr=8-1&keywords=steadicam+with+tripod) white-label one? In my opinion, lenses aren't usually necessary, but if you insist take a look at 'Moment': they seem to be the industry standard, and make amazing quality lenses with minimal distortion or abboration, and best of all they support the S8 as well. I'm not sure what type of budget you're going for, but this is my suggestion for a pro-sumer/enthusiast.